# Pandas Calculate CAGR with Slicing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                       'B' : [7,6,5,4],
                       'C' : [5,6,7,1],
                       'D' : [1,9,9,8]})
df=df.set_index('A')
df
    B   C   D
A           
1   7   5   1
2   6   6   9
3   5   7   9
7   4   1   8
```

I am attempting to calculate the [compound annual growth rate (CAGR)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp?layout=infini&v=5A&adtest=5A&ato=3000).
I am trying to avoid using the column names.
Here's what I came up with:

```
df['CAGR']=((df[df.columns[-1:]]/df[df.columns[:1]])**(1/len(df.columns)))-1
```

However, it throws this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

I tested each part of the formula and it returned the columns I needed, so I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slicing the `DataFrame` in such a way that the return object is a `DataFrame`

```
df[df.columns[-1:]]
```

The `-1:` results in `df.columns[-1:]` returning `[column_name]` instead of `column_name`.  As a consequence, `df[df.columns[-1:]]` is a `DataFrame`.  What that means is that when you try to do the division, `pandas` tries to line up the indices, columns included.  To get around this.  You could have just done:

```
df[df.columns[-1]]
```

Using `-1` instead of `-1:`

However, I would have done it like this.

```
df['CAGR'] = df.iloc[:, -1].div(df.iloc[:, 0]).pow(1./(len(df.columns) - 1)).sub(1)

print df

   B  C  D      CAGR
A                   
1  7  5  1 -0.622036
2  6  6  9  0.224745
3  5  7  9  0.341641
7  4  1  8  0.414214
```

Comment: Ensures that the 1 is a float

Comment: Follow-up question posted here (for the case of missing values): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400872/pandas-calculate-cagr-with-slicing-missing-values

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want compound annual growth per row of `df`

```
df['CAGR'] = df.T.pct_change().add(1).prod().pow(1./(len(df.columns) - 1)).sub(1)

print df

   B  C  D      CAGR
A                   
1  7  5  1 -0.622036
2  6  6  9  0.224745
3  5  7  9  0.341641
7  4  1  8  0.414214
```

#### Explanation

1. Transpose to use other easy `pandas` methods
2. pct_change then add back 1
3. multiply all
4. take the root.  Note, this needs to be 1 less than the number of observations.  As the return requires 2 observations.

Comment: Not OP, but a novice learning Pandas. I have a couple of questions for your answer: what does `.prod()` do in your code? Is it corresponding to the "multiply all" part in your explanation? If so, which part is multiplying? Another question is that I see you can put multiple "." function for a dataframe together, here it's `df.T.pct_change().add.prod` honestly didn't know that. So if you have multiple "." part, does the function closest to the beginning (df) get called first? Thank you.

Comment: @BowenLiu `prod` is a the `pandas.DataFrame` method that multiplies all.  By default, it multiplies all values in columns.  You could pass an `axis=1` argument to multiply all in rows.  The dot operator (`.`) is a Python thing.  It is used to access an objects attributes.  Python allows you to use another dot operation on the thing returned from the prior dot operation.  In this case, `df.T` returns another dataframe and that new dataframe has a `pct_change` method that I'm free to use.  However, this would have been the same as `df.pct_change(axis=1)`

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your timely reply. I was reading related material in order to understand your comment. I'm also testing your code piece by piece to see what each part does. Sorry for being slow, but I still don't understand what `prod` does. You said it will multiply all, but multiply with what? What are the two parts needed for the multiply function? And what does "number of observation" mean? But my biggest question, your input `df` is a data frame up until the `add(1)`part, which function makes it into a data series? Thanks again

Comment: I am assuming that `prod` does the trick, since `df.T.pct_change().add(1)` still returns a dataframe, but 'df.T.pct_change().add(1).prod()' will return a data series. Wait a second, `prod` will literally multiply EVERY SINGLE number in the same row doesn't it? I think I may have just understood it. No wonder it returns a data serie.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I usually use the `apply` method for Pandas dataframes, since it allows me to have more flexibility in the parameters of my function.

For instance in the following function:

```py
def CAGR(x, last_col, first_col, num_periods):
    """ Calculate compound growth rate on a row x of a pandas df"""
    val_T = float(x[last_col])
    val_t = x[first_col]        
    return (val_T/val_t)**(1./num_periods)-1
```

You can both provide columns with their position or with their name (which may be useful once you want to calculate the CAGR on two arbitrary columns of the dataset):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['1','2','3','7'],
    'B' : [7,6,5,4],
    'C' : [5,6,7,1],
    'D' : [1,9,9,8]
})

df=df.set_index('A')

CAGR_a = df.apply(
    func=CAGR,    
    axis=1, 
    # positional arguments (i.e. order matters)
    args=(df.columns[-1],df.columns[0], len(df.columns)-1)
)

CAGR_b = df.apply(
    func=CAGR,    
    axis=1,     
    args=('D','B', len(df.columns)-1)
)
print(CAGR_a.equals(CAGR_b))
True
```

Then you should get the desired result:

```
df['CAGR'] = CAGR_a
print(df)
   B  C  D      CAGR
A                   
1  7  5  1 -0.622036
2  6  6  9  0.224745
3  5  7  9  0.341641
7  4  1  8  0.414214
```