# Pandas Calculate CAGR with Slicing (missing values)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355924/pandas-calculate-cagr-with-slicing/37356166?noredirect=1#comment62300488_37356166), 
I'd like to calculate the CAGR from a pandas data frame such as this, where there are some missing data values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                       'B' : [7,6,np.nan,4],
                       'C' : [5,6,7,1],
                       'D' : [np.nan,9,9,8]})
df=df.set_index('A')
df
    B   C   D
A           
1   7   5   NaN
2   6   6   9
3   NaN 7   9
7   4   1   8
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating returns from a level, it's ok to use most recent available.  For example, when calculating CAGR for row 1, we want to use  (5/7) ^ (1/3) - 1.  Also, for row 3 (9/7) ^ (1/3).  There is an assumption made that we annualize across all years looked at.

With these assumptions:

```
df = df.bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1)
```

Then apply solution from linked question.

```
df['CAGR'] = df.T.pct_change().add(1).prod().pow(1./(len(df.columns) - 1)).sub(1)
```

With out this assumption.  The only other reasonable choice would be to annualize by the number of non-NaN observations.  So I need to track that with:

```
notnull = df.notnull().sum(axis=1)
df = df.bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1)
df['CAGR'] = df.T.pct_change().add(1).prod().pow(1./(notnull.sub(1))).sub(1)
```

In fact, this becomes the more general solution as it will work with the case with out nulls as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm just getting into analyzing financial data and your help is making it much more enjoyable.

Comment: glad I could help.